# Trying to animate a snackbar in Svelte, using different animations for when it appears and disappears

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

My current goal is to build a Material-esque snackbar component that will appear from the bottom of the screen, and then blur once the action to dismiss the snackbar is taken. My current code looks like this

```
<script lang="ts">
    import '../css/snackbar.css';

    import { linear } from 'svelte/easing';
    import { blur, fly } from 'svelte/transition';

    let show = true;

    export let message: string;
    export let actionText: string = 'Dismiss';

    let options = { duration: 350, easing: linear };
</script>

{#if show}
    <div
        class="snackbar"
        class:snackbar-active={Boolean(message)}
        transition:blur={options}
    >
        <div class="snackbar-text">
            {message}
        </div>
        <button class="link" on:click={() => (show = !show)}>{actionText}</button>
    </div>
{:else}
    <div
        class="snackbar"
        class:snackbar-active={Boolean(message)}
        transition:fly={{ ...options, opacity: 1, y: 600 }}
    >
        <div class="snackbar-text">
            {message}
        </div>
        <button class="link" on:click={() => (show = !show)}>{actionText}</button>
    </div>
{/if}
```

And the CSS:

```
.snackbar {
    align-items: flex-end center;
    background: var(--project-color-surface-variant);
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: flex-end center;
    padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem 0.625rem 1.25rem;
    position: fixed;
    width: fit-content;
    z-index: 9;
}
.snackbar .link {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: var(--project-color-secondary);
    display: inline-flex;
    padding-left: 1.25rem;
}
```

In it's current state, the snackbar will initially appear from the bottom of the screen, and then blur away on clicking the `actionText`. But then it will immediately fly back in from the top, then blur on click, and start the cycle over by appearing from the bottom.

What I want is for it to appear whenever it is triggered on a page, and then when it is clicked, it will disappear without coming back.

I've tried CSS keyframes for other transitions but I couldn't quite get it the way I wanted. When I discovered the transitions that Svelte had built-in, I wanted to try those. They're nice, I just want this instance to work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `if`/`else`, there should only be one the `if` branch and you can switch out the transitions using `in:` and `out:`.

```html
{#if show}
    <div
        class="snackbar"
        class:snackbar-active={Boolean(message)}
        in:fly={{ ...options, opacity: 1, y: 600 }}
        out:blur={options}>
        <div class="snackbar-text">
            {message}
        </div>
        <button class="link" on:click={() => (show = !show)}>{actionText}</button>
    </div>
{/if}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/8e7fd152f0e149469599c89409d79965?version=3.49.0)

Comment: I tried this, the only issue is the the `in:fly` doesn't seem to work. The snackbar just appears without any kind of animation.

Comment: Have you looked at the REPL?